# how to close smooth-box master jquery image by Esc button?

Tags: jquery

I have used the following..can some one help me?

```
.on("click",".sb-cancel",function(e){$(".smoothbox").fadeOut("slow",function(){$(".smoothbox").remove()})
```

Comment: For one.. that javascript is invalid. It doesn't close the `.on` and first callback. It should end with another `});`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it should work that way:

```
.on("click",".sb-cancel",function() {
    $(".smoothbox").fadeOut("slow",function() {
        $(".smoothbox").remove();
    });
});
```